# The polarization filter does not work

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, polarization, photoelectric-effect

I am working in  Conduction phenomena
Photo-conductivity Experiment. 
Here the 
[experiment guide](https://www.ld-didactic.de/documents/en-US/EXP/P/P7/P7231_e.pdf?__hstc=98968833.94f2e00748f594cd1c1e829b9eff5d1b.1569347043106.1569347043106.1569347043106.1&__hssc=98968833.3.1569347043110&__hsfp=3258062130&_ga=2.16844092.400357689.1569347039-1927031351.1569347039) .
The aim is to measure the photocurrent $I_{Ph}$ as a function of the voltage $U$ at a constant irradiance.

The problem is the photocurrent  has the same value when i change the polarization angle from 0 to 30 to 60 to 90. 
It seems that the polarization filters does not work or does not change the amount of the irradiance. 
Knowing that i turn off the light while doing this experiment, but there is the sun light coming from  high window that i can't cover.

So anyone can help me in that?

Here the result that i should have:
[image]

And here my result:

[image]

there is no different in the photocurrent of the photo-resistor when i change the the polarization angle between the two filter

Comment: Did you check whether you are using the filters correctly by just looking at them and noticing a difference in transparency when you rotate one of them?

Comment: There are different types of polarization filters.  Circular polarization filters are ordinary linear polarizers on one side and quarter - wave plates on the other side.  You might be using the wrong kind if filter.  Test this by reversing one of your filters.

Comment: If that doesn't change your results, reverse the other filter.  And, try reversing both of them.

Comment: thank you all i am going to try these and comeback